# Finitely generated group is a subquotient of SL_2(C)

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, free-groups, finitely-generated

We already know that $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ generate a free subgroup of $GL_2 (\mathbb{C})$. But we are then asked to conclude that every finitely generated group is a subquotient (i.e. quotient of a subgroup) of $SL_2 (\mathbb{C})$.

I don’t quite see the relation between them, so I barely know where to start. Could anyone give me some hint on doing this?

Comment: Every finitely generated group? Do you mean every finitely generated subgroup of $\text{GL}_2$ or something?

Comment: Why are you writing $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$, and not $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ as in the title?

Comment: @AlexClark it’s not specified in the problem but I suppose it is in GL2C

Comment: @DietrichBurde because that’s exactly what the problem states lol

Answer (score 1):

Given any positive integer $m$, the
 free group of rank $2$ has a subgroup which is free of rank $m$.
Any group with $m$ generators is isomorphic to a quotient of this, and
so to a quotient of a subgroup of your group.